# Wpf listview item selection event

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have two ListView, each list contains some row's. I want to call function after row selection. But i have a problem, event "GotFocus" firing when row selected or button in this row clicked. When i use `<i:EventTrigger EventName="Selected">` it is not firing when row in table is selected. What i need to do?

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Width="200" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding .}">
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainWindow }}}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListView>
    <ListBox Width="200" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding .}">
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.TestTestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainWindow }}}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication129
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new Data();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public ICommand TestCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand TestTestCommand { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    public Data()
    {
        TestCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Test());
        TestTestCommand = new RelayCommand(() => TestTest());
        Items = new List<string>();
        Items.Add("first");
        Items.Add("Second");
        Items.Add("Third");
    }
    public void Test()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Running");
    }
    public void TestTest()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TestRunning");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is `Selected` event? Where do you find/use it?

Comment: <i:EventTrigger EventName="Selected">

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `Selected` event in `ListView`, you have to use [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) event.